# SSRS report: {2008-r2} (.rdl file) Tablix -- Add Horizontal scrollbar to data

Tags: xml, ssrs-2008-r2, horizontal-scrolling, rdl

SSRS report: {2008-r2} (.rdl file)  Tablix -- Add Horizontal scrollbar to data

I am trying to add a horizontal scrollbar to an SSRS report with many columns.

The rdl file is written in xml or an xml-like language.

When I try to add a tag (and its closing tag):

```
 <Scrollview>
 ...
</Scrollview>
```

I get a complier error:

```
[rsInvalidReportDefinition] The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services...
```

What would be the appropriate way to add a horizontal-scrollbar to the columns within an rdl file for SSRS reports?

*NOTE:*  This project does not have a .css file at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont you get a horizontal scroll bar once you start adding enough columns. Depending on your version of IE and where your deploying to i.e. sharepoint or report server , you will start to see horizontal bar appear once you reach towards end of page 1. Ofcouse in sharepoint you have options on adding more width to report part; which you do not have option of in report server mode. We have many reports in sharepoint mode and users who view rdl without downloading it do view columns all the way at end (if not we would have gotten tickets about it) or QA-team would have sent it back suggesting columns are not visible.

Comment: The only convenient way to move right through the columns is to use the "right arrow" key (->) and on my browser (edge) a scrollbar does *NOT* appear.

Comment: try opening it with IE.

Comment: It is essentially the same in IE, certainly no scrollbar appears.  Once again, I  use the "right arrow" key (->)

Comment: Are there any other answers out there?